# MSACCESS - How to add a primary key using a query make table

Tags: sql, ms-access, select-into

I have a query make table with this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblStore.Position, tblStore.Branch, tblStore.Location, tblStore.Operator INTO tblAllPositions
FROM tblStore
WHERE (((tblStore.Position) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY tblStore.Position, tblStore.Branch, tblStore.Location;
```

I want to add to the new table `tblAllPositions` a field called `ID_Positions` and set it as primary key autonumber.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
ALTER TABLE tblAllPositions 
ADD COLUMN ID_Positions COUNTER, 
CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY (ID_Positions)
```

I constructed that SQL after review of ALTER TABLE and CREATE TABLE tutorials at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/data-definition-language